# DVD writer not working properly

Tags: dvd

I am using a sony vaio VPCEH15EN laptop.
I am not able to play any DVD's on my computer but I am able to play CDs.
How can I know what the problem is?  Is there any software to detect problems on devices for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install restricted or just dvdread, then run the dvd decoder installation script:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

Comment: It's not a problem with restricted DVD's. My DVD's were working fine before but the are just shown as blank media in ubuntu as well as windows

Comment: Then I suspect it's a failing optical drive.  I had that on an old HP laptop.  It started skipping, then started showing blank, then failed to mount altogether.  I can now see failed ioctl calls or some such in dmesg at every boot of that laptop.  It's worth noting that your DVD reads would fail first, since they require a higher read speed/spin speed/accuracy than CDs by a metric of about 5x.

Comment: Can the os detect if the drive is failing?

Comment: It will detect it once it fails altogether, but not while it is slowly starting to fail.

Comment: What might be the problem could it be the lens?

Comment: It could be any part of the drive.  In my case it was a motor that didn't spin up right any more.  It could be something as simple as a lens cleaning, but I suspect if it were you would have just done that instead of asking a question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9955/discussion-between-hbdgaf-and-m-tarun)

Comment: marking as resolved and moving on.